# load data into an udf python for pig

Tags: python, apache-pig

I'm writing an UDF function for PIG using python. I found a problem because I need to load some data from a file to compute the udf results.

I will exaplain my idea using an example. My idea was to write 2 functions where one is for initialization:

```
abbr = []   
def set (filename):
    file = open(filename, "r")
    for i in file:
        abbr.append(i)

@outputSchema("out:chararray")
def get (line):
    for i in abbr:
        if line.endswith(i):
            return "yes"
    return "no"
```

my PIG script should call one time "set" before using "get". But I do not know how. I also tried to use a class with a constructor, but I didn't manage to call the member function "get".

Could someone help me?

**UPDATE:**

I "resolved" for now with a not very beautiful workaround:

```
abbr = []
@outputSchema("out:chararray")
def get (line):
    if len(abbr)==0:
        file = open("file.txt", "r")
        for i in file:
            abbr.append(i)
    for i in abbr:
        if line.endswith(i):
            return "yes"
        return "no"
```